# fullcalendar: find just created event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

On my calendar user can select a period of time and create a new event.
BUT: since select function doesn't pass the current event, i need to fake click jsEvent on the current event as soon as is created.

My problem:
How can i find out which event i just have been created by select?

so far i tried `renderEvent` and `eventAfterRender` but the first one doesn't give me any DOM element where i can attach my click event and the second one return a list of all rendered event in my calendar!

```
   events: [
    {
      title: "80$",
      start: "01-11-2016",
      end: "10-11-2016"

    }
    ],
    editable: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        selectOverlap: false,

        select: function(start, end, jsEvent) {
            var check = start._d.toJSON().slice(0,10);
        var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
            if(check > today ){

                list.eventUpdated = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end"
                };

                $(cal).fullCalendar('addEventSource', {
                  events: [list.eventUpdated]
                });

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
        },

        eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
            console.log(event); // give all events in my cal
            // my goal is do something like:
            // event.click();
        },

        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent) {
          // do stuff with datepicker
        }
```

I saw this similar topic but i couldn't replicate it so far :/
[Trigger once after event created using fullcalendar.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577487/trigger-once-after-event-created-using-fullcalendar-io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom property to the new event object before rendering it saying 'hey, this is from a select action'. On your eventRender callback, check for that set property. eventRender gives you the event and the DOM object.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnmwmze9/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
        ...
        select: function (start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    fromSelect: true
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        eventAfterRender: function(event, element){
            if(event.fromSelect){
                //Now you have the event and the DOM element
                event.fromSelect = false; //(as to not trigger on rerender)
                element.click();
            }
        },
        eventClick: function(event, element){
            console.log(event);
            //do something here
        },
        ...
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the click() is not gonna work here because the DOM element isn't rendered yet. I should use `eventAfterRender` which i tried but if it end up in an infinitive loop :/

Comment: Ah, did not see the "fake click" mentioned in the post. I think you are on the right track with eventAfterRender though. I was able to get it to simulate a click without an infinite loop. I updated the answer and fiddle. Have a look and let me know if this is similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yesss!!! This is awesome! working perfectly, thanks! I was going crazy with this infinitive loop :)